# splice() is not emptying the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below code should return empty array but it is returning Banana,Banana,Banana

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana"];

fruits.map((ele) => {
  if (ele === "Banana") {
    fruits.splice(0, 1)
  }
})

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Any reason you are avoiding `array#filter`?

Comment: `filter` is the better option here. `const out = fruits.filter(el => el !== 'Banana')`.

Comment: This is because when you mutate the array inside the map, you skip the index every time you `splice`. You better use `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually doing what you're telling it.

An implementation of `array.map` could be like this:

```
array.prototype.map = function(transform) {
    let output = [];
    for(let index = 0; index < this.length; ++index) {
          output.push(transform(this[index]));
    }
    return output;
}
```

The loop would go like this:

- `Index = 0, length = 6, remove first item`
- `Index = 1, length = 5, remove first remaining item`
- `Index = 2, length = 4, remove first remaining item`
- `Index = 3, length = 3, terminate loop`

This is why it is only removing three items.

The upshot of this is that `array.map` is the inappropriate function for the job.

There's a number of ways you can implement this. One way is to iterate through the array backwards:

```
for(let index = fruits.length-1; index >= 0; --index) {
    if(fruits[index] === 'Banana') {
        fruits.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

An example:

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Apple", "Banana", "Banana", "Orange", "Banana"];

for(let index = fruits.length-1; index >= 0; --index) {
    if(fruits[index] === 'Banana') {
        fruits.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

console.log(fruits);
```

```html
<div class="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.forEach()` goes in a forward direction (ex. `0...5`) so if an element is removed then the length decreases as the length decreases to half to of the length, the index reference will be greater than the length -- hence half of the array remains.

When decreasing the length of an array, go in the revearse direcrtion (ex. `5...0`). The example below uses a reverse for loop and `.splice(i, 1)`.

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana"];

for (let i = fruits.length; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (fruits[i] === "Banana") {
    fruits.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

console.log(fruits);
```

Comment: This is only removing the last item. Imagine if if was ["Banana", "Apple"], it would remove "Apple".

Comment: Also the first index to `fruits[i]` would be `fruits[fruits.length]`, which would be out of the array range. You would need to initialize `i` to `fruits.length-1`.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd you're right about the `.pop()` changed to `.splice(i, 1)` on the offset `i >= 0` seems to keep everthing within range.